# Connecting iOS app with PostgreSQL through a server

Tags: swift, postgresql, swift3

What is the recommended way of connecting an iOS app with a PostgreSQL database?

There seem to be Swift PostgreSQL drivers already, [this is one of them](https://github.com/stepanhruda/PostgreSQL-Swift). However isn't it best practice to connect to a database through a server? What servers are recommended for this?

Comment: You've already answered your own question.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I'm wondering what kind of servers typically used to connect an iOS app with a PostgreSQL server. Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever server is hosting your Postgres database.